# Can not convert from String to float

Tags: java, android, string

I have a problem. When I took some value from view and try to parse it to float for example 2.1234567 it's ok, but when the value is longer nothing happend.

```
private View.OnClickListener buttonListenerNumber = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        numberAsString += ((Button)view ).getText().toString();

        if(signStatus)
        {
            dotStatus = false;
            secondNumber = Float.parseFloat(numberAsString);
            textView.setText(Float.toString(secondNumber));
        }else
        {
            firstNumber = Float.parseFloat(numberAsString);
            textView.setText(Float.toString(firstNumber));
        }

        if(firstNumber != 0 && secondNumber != 0 && secendSignStatus || equalStatus )
        {
            try{
                takeAction(lastSign);
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(NAN));
            }

        }
    }
};
```

And when i debug it's look like this 
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by nothing happend ?

Comment: `secondNumber` remains `""`. That's what he means

Comment: because i add only to firstNumber in this case

Comment: But look at your code.  You set `secondNumber` in the "then" branch and `firstNumber` in the "else" branch of the same `if` statement.  Obviously, you can't set both in the same `onClick` call.   Or do you mean something else?  Your question and comments are **not clear**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid trimming use `Double.parseDouble(String)` instead

float has a limitation of smaller size (4 bytes) so it's not good for big decimals, double has the double size (8 bytes)